# rails 4 many to many form saving and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, many-to-many

I have many-to-many relationship and I want to use checkboxes to select relationships that I need. 
Controller (I use scaffold)

```
...
  def update
    #params[:characteristic][:property_ids] ||= []
    respond_to do |format|
      if @characteristic.update(characteristic_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @characteristic, notice: 'Characteristic was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @characteristic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
...
    def characteristic_params
      params[:characteristic][:property_ids] ||= []
      params.require(:characteristic).permit(:characteristicable_id, :characteristicable_type, :property_ids)

    end
```

Model

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :characteristics
  mount_uploader :image, PropertyUploader
end

class Characteristic < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :properties
end
```

My form for characteristic

```
<%= form_for(@characteristic) do |f| %>
  <% if @characteristic.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@characteristic.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this characteristic from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @characteristic.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>

  <% end %>

    <% for  p in Property.find(:all) %>
        <p>
        <%= check_box_tag "characteristic[:property_ids][]", p.id, @characteristic.properties.include?(p)  %>
        <%= image_tag p.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
        <%= p.name %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I select checkboxes and save my relationship doesn't saves but notice says that updating\saving was successfull. If I don't check any checkbox there is error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
params[:characteristic][:property_ids] ||= []
```

**SOLVED**

```
<%= check_box_tag "characteristic[:property_ids][]", p.id, @characteristic.properties.include?(p)  %>
```

I changed to

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "characteristic[property_ids][]", '' %>
...
<%= check_box_tag "characteristic[property_ids][]", p.id, @characteristic.properties.include?(p)  %>
```

and in controller

```
def characteristic_params
          params[:characteristic][:property_ids] ||= []
          params.require(:characteristic).permit(:characteristicable_id, :characteristicable_type, :property_ids)

        end
```

to

```
def characteristic_params
  params.require(:characteristic).permit(:characteristicable_id, :characteristicable_type, { :property_ids => [] })
end
```

I followed [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes) but Rails 4 expects HABTM as **{:child_id => []}** and form should have **parentmodel[child_ids][]** but not **parentmodel[:child_ids][]** or it will cause "Unpermitted parameters: :child_ids"

Answer (score 0):

If `params[:characteristic]` does not exist, it will return `nil`.  If it returns `nil`, then you're calling `nil[:property_ids]`, which will throw an error since nil doesn't support the bracket notation.

A straightforward way around this would be with a ternary operator:

```
ids = params[:characteristic] ? params[:characteristic][:property_ids] : []
```

Then you could `merge` the `ids` into `params` if that's what you want to do.  You may have to adjust the data types to match up (array vs hash), depending on how they're coming in, but this will get you past the `undefined method` error.